# Is it possible to check if a user has pasted something?

Tags: android

I'm trying to count how many times a user has copied something from my app and pasted it to anywhere outside my app. Sounds rather unlikely to me, but is it in any way possible to see when a user has pasted anything?

I can't find anything about it in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/clipboard/copy-paste.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, sorry -- once you put something on the clipboard, it is no longer yours, and you cannot track its usage.